# Как преобразовать структуру в иерархическую?

Tags: javascript, json

Как преобразовать плоскую структуру в виде дерева где есть id и parent_id.
В иерархическую вложенную?

Исходная:

```
[{
  id: 1
},{
  id: 3,
  parent_id: 1
},
{
  id: 4,
  parent_id: 3
},{
  id: 5,
  parent_id: 3
},{
  id: 6,
  parent_id: 1
}]
```

В иерархическую

```
[{
  id:1,
  children: [
  {
    id: 3,
    children: [{
      id: 4
    },{
      id: 5
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 6
  }]
}]
```

---

Готовый алгоритм:

```
/**
 * Преобразование плоской структуры в иерархическую
 * @param  {Array} flat плоский массив где есть свойства id и parentId
 * @return {JSON}      иерархический массив со свойствами children
 */
    function flatToHierarchy(flat) {
      const roots = [];
      const all = {};
      flat.forEach((item) => {
        all[item.id] = item;
      });
      Object.keys(all).forEach((id) => {
        const item = all[id];
        if (item.parentId === null || (!item.parentId)) {
          roots.push(item);
        } else if (item.parentId in all) {
          const p = all[item.parentId];
          if (!('children' in p)) {
            p.children = [];
          }
          p.children.push(item);
        }
      });
      return roots;
    }

const Harray = flatToHierarchy(array)
```

Comment: А как пытались преобразовать? Может нужно просто что-то подправить в Вашем коде да и все?

Comment: Пока непонятно какой алгоритм использовать.

Comment: Да хоть обход массива. Смотрим `parent_id` (кстати, в JS принято писать имена свойств в pascalCase), потом ищем нужный `id`, добавляем ему свойство `children` и вставляем туда текущий элемент

Comment: Ну в том ответе лишняя информация про html. А в моем вопросе речь чисто про JSON.

Comment: Я тоже соглашусь, что в дубликате много лишнего - HTML, рекурсия, код на полтора экрана... С точки зрения полезности, этот вопрос лучше того.

Comment: Только один вопрос массив который преобразовать нужно он одномерный, всегда?

Comment: @user3126867
Исходный массив да. Но логическая вложенность может быть любой глубины.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так

```js
var arrFlat = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 3, parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 4, parent_id: 3 },
    { id: 5, parent_id: 3 },
    { id: 6, parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 7, parent_id: 6 },
    { id: 8, parent_id: 7 },
    { id: 9, parent_id: null },
    { id: 10, parent_id: 123 } // типа нет такого родителя
];

function flatToHierarchy ( flat ) {
    const roots = [ ],
            map = [ ],
            id = [ ];
    flat.forEach( item => {
        map.push( Object.assign( { }, item ) ); // копируем
        id.push( item.id );
    } );
    let i;
    map.forEach( item => {
        // Не пойму зачем вы вставили сюда null !?
        if ( /*item.parent_id === null ||*/ !item.parent_id || ( i = id.indexOf( item.parent_id ) ) === -1 ) {
            roots.push( item );
            return;
        }
        if ( map[i].children ) {
            map[i].children.push( item );
        }
        else {
            map[i].children = [ item ];
        }
    } );
    return roots;
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( flatToHierarchy( arrFlat ), null, 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой ответ интересует? Вроде выглядит правильно, насколько могу судить, но меня смущает, что в вашем примере в выводе у вложенных элементов отсутствуют `parent_id`. Я их не убираю в своем ответе, но, если что, можно этот момент пересмотреть.

```js
let source = [{
    id: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    parent_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    parent_id: 3
  }, {
    id: 5,
    parent_id: 3
  }, {
    id: 6,
    parent_id: 1
  }
];

let res = source.reduce((acc, curr, index, orig) => {
  if (curr.parent_id) {
    let parent = orig.find(item => {
      return item.id === curr.parent_id;
    });

    (parent.children = parent.children || []).push(curr);
    return acc;
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
    return acc;
  }
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

По факту основная трудность в подобных задачах (по крайней мере лично для меня) заключается в том, чтобы в верхний уровень результирующего массива попали только *некоторые* элементы исходного массива. Проблема, очевидно, в том, что большинство методов (`map`, `forEach` и т.п.) не позволяют без костылей менять длину входного массива, а, как известно, тряски со `splice` внутри циклов обычно ничем хорошим не заканчиваются.

Собственно, отсюда было принято решение использовать `reduce`, поскольку это один из немногих способов (с более или менее читаемым кодом на выходе), который позволяет обработать входной массив таким образом, что на выходе будет любое другое значение (даже, вероятно, другого типа). В данном случае - совершенно новый массив, в который попадут только *некоторые* элементы исходного.

**Суть** работы моего примера в том, чтобы на каждой итерации найти в оригинальном массиве родительский элемент для текущего элемента и поместить его в `children` родителя; при этом, если родительского элемента для текущего элемента не существует, то его (сам элемент) нужно просто поместить прямо в результирующий массив.

Очевидно, из-за поиска внутри `reduce` сложность алгоритма хромает, и, насколько я могу судить (а тут я не силён), примерно равна `O(n^2)` (что довольно печально).

Comment: Вам надо немного изменить код, возможно родитель `parent` с таким `id` не будет найдет, это вызовет ошибку. И элементы(объекты), наверное, все же нужно копировать `Object.assign`, иначе изменяется оригинальный объект.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Учитывая, что (насколько я понял) исходные данные приходят откуда-то с сервера, то вероятность того, что данные будут битыми (невозможно будет найти родителя) ничтожно мала. А что касается копирования, то этого по возможности вообще всегда лучше избегать, ибо это крайне непроизводительно. А уж тем более копирование через `assign` - тот еще геморрой (не глубокое (1), не учитывает наследование (2)). Тем более, автор вопроса про сохранение оригинального массива ничего не говорил.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg а, вы и есть автор вопроса :)

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg В таком случае пусть мои слова выше будут вам поводом поразмыслить. В вашем текущем случае оно может пока и ничего через `assign` копировать, но если появятся вложенные структуры, прототипное наследование и все в этом духе, то можете потом часы потратить на поиск источника бага :) **Кстати**, "готовый алгоритм", что вы привели, - это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос? Вы для code review его приложили? Или это нерабочий код?

Comment: нет я не автор(я как и вы ответ дал), на счет копирования согласен, возможно входной объект далее не понадобиться. Просто попробовал ваш код и у меня он вызвал ошибку, но я спецом несуществующий `id` добавил.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg черт, опять не туда посмотрел :) В общем, подождем, что автор вопроса скажет, в таком случае.

Answer (score 0):

Облазил пол-интернета - не нашёл на php.
Сделал сам - положу к вашему посту (может, кому надо).

```
<?php

$a = [
    1 => ['id' => 1],
    2 => ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 5],
    3 => ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1],
    4 => ['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3],
    5 => ['id' => 5],
];

function hierarchicalByParent(array $data, string $parentField = 'parent_id', string $childrenField = 'nodes') {
    $root = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        if (empty($val[$parentField])) {
            $root[] = &$data[$key];
        } else {
            $data[$val[$parentField]][$childrenField][] = &$data[$key];
        }
    }
    return $root;
}

$b = hierarchicalByParent($a);
var_export($b);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]