# Как преобразовать одномерный массив с объектами в многомерный

Tags: javascript, массивы, дерево

Есть одномерный массив с объектами дерева, у каждого объекта указан parent.

Root parent всегда один, у каждого элемента есть уникальный id, массив не отсортирован, можно использовать либы (lodash например).

Принимается любая идея.

Выложил в песочницу то, что должнобыть на входе и выходе

```js
const TreeData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "root",
    "parent": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "level 1 [0]",
    "parent": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "level 1 [1]",
    "parent": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "level 2 [1.0]",
    "parent": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "level 2 [1.1]",
    "parent": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "title": "level 2 [0.0]",
    "parent": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "title": "level 2 [0.1]",
    "parent": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "level 3 [0.0.0]",
    "parent": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "title": "level 3 [0.0.1]",
    "parent": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "level 3 [0.1.0]",
    "parent": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "level 3 [0.1.1]",
    "parent": 7
  }
];

const TreeDataFormatted = {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "root",
  "child": [{
      "id": 2,
      "title": "level 1 [0]",
      "child": [{
          "id": 6,
          "title": "level 2 [0.0]",
          "child": [{
              "id": 8,
              "title": "level 3 [0.0.0]"
            },
            {
              "id": 9,
              "title": "level 3 [0.0.1]"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "title": "level 2 [0.1]",
          "child": [{
              "id": 10,
              "title": "level 3 [0.1.0]",
              "parent": 7
            },
            {
              "id": 11,
              "title": "level 3 [0.1.1]",
              "parent": 7
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "level 1 [1]",
      "child": [{
          "id": 4,
          "title": "level 2 [1.0]",
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "title": "level 2 [1.1]",
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};
```

Comment: Точно, не знал как загуглить спасибо.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать структуру в иерархическую?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958143/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E)